# Python (Flask) - Show loading message/gif for matplotlib generated image (html)

Tags: python, html, image, matplotlib, flask

I am fairly new to web development in general, so this question might show some inexperience. My apologies.

**Working application**: user inputs x- and y values in the /showgraph route --> matplotlib generates the plot which is shown in the same route.

Here is the code part similar to my problem:

**html**:

```
...
<form class="graphs" method="POST", action="{{ url_for('showgraph') }}">
  <input placeholder="x-value" name="valx" id="xvalue">
  <input placeholder="y-value" name="valy" id="yvalue">
  <input type="submit" name="showgraph" value="Show Graph" id="inputvalues">
</form>
{% if buttonclick[0]=="Show Graph" %}   
    <img src="{{ url_for('fig', val=val) }}" alt="Image Placeholder"  height="400">
{% endif %}
...
```

**Python (using Flask)**

```
@app.route('/fig/<val>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fig(val):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
    import StringIO
    import ast
    val=ast.literal_eval(str(val))
    x=[float(i) for i in val[0][0].strip('[]').split(',')]
    y=[float(i) for i in val[1][0].strip('[]').split(',')]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    img = StringIO.StringIO()
    fig.savefig(img)
    img.seek(0)
    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')


@app.route('/showgraph/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def showgraph():
   valx=(request.form.getlist('valx'))
   valy=(request.form.getlist('valy'))
   val='('+str(valx)+','+str(valy)+')'
   buttonclick=request.form.getlist('showgraph') 
   return render_template("graphs.html",buttonclick=buttonclick,val=val)
```

Now when I enter some x and y values (e.g x=[1,2,3] and y=[3,2,1]) the page shows the alt ("Image placeholder") first and after 5 or 6 seconds the image (graph) is shown.

Is there a way to to overcome this problem and just show a loading message,gif,..?

(I'm still working on a more efficient and cleaner method to make an array of the input values. I can imagine this method might look a bit devious for some. )

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lowsrc attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_lowsrc.asp) of the img tag. Instead of

```
<img src="{{ url_for('fig', val=val) }}" alt="Image Placeholder"  height="400">
```

try

```
<img src="{{ url_for('fig', val=val) }}" alt="Image Placeholder"  height="400" 
     lowsrc="/images/loading.gif">
```

where `loading.gif` is a placeholder image that shows a (possibly animated?) loading message.

Hint: You can create loading gifs at http://www.ajaxload.info/

Comment: This doesn't seem to to solve the problem. I also tried to solve it with CSS (background-image) but got the same result.